# Python not equal 'for' iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

During the iteration over the text file and over the list I've found the unexpected behavior of `for` loop.
Text file `test.txt` consists of only two strings: 1) `He said:` and 2) `We said:`.
First `for`+`for` loop

```
file_ = open('c:\\Python27\\test.txt', 'r')
list_ = ['Alpha','Bravo','Charlie']
try:
    for string in file_:
        for element in list_:
            print string, element
except StandardError:
    print 'Ooops'
```

returns absolutely expectable result:

```
He said: Alpha
He said: Bravo
He said: Charlie
We said: Alpha
We said: Bravo
We said: Charlie
```

But if the `for` order was changed to

```
file_ = open('c:\\Python27\\test.txt', 'r')
list_ = ['Alpha','Bravo','Charlie']
try:
    for element in list_:
        for string in file_:
            print string, element
except StandardError:
    print 'Ooops'
```

the result is totally different:

```
He said: Alpha
We said: Alpha
```

Looks like the first `for` became uniterable. Why?

Comment: Is that all of the code ?

Comment: `lines = file.readlines()` then just do your iteration over the `lines` list.

Answer (score 3):

When you complete the for loop over the file, you "consume" it. You would have to go back to its beginning for each iteration of the outer loop with `file_.seek(0)`. Or use the original loop ordering.

You can replicate the behaviour with this simplified example:

```
    for string in file_:
        print string

    for string in file_:
        print string
```

where you'll see the second loop does nothing.

Comment: Thanks, it's very forceful example

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `file_.seek(0)` to return to the beginning of the file in order to re-iterate through its contents.

You have iterated through it via : `for string in file_:` and so the current position, obtained by calling `file_.tell()`, will be the size of the file in bytes (if I am not mistaken), signifying the end.